# Using 'in some time'

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible to say "in some time" in English?
For example " I'll see you in some time" (I'm not sure whether I'll see the person in 1 or 2 weeks)

Comment: In your example, no. Just use "I'll see you sometime". Some more examples would improve this question.

Comment: But is there such phrase in English? And if so, how can I use it? That is the main problem, I haven't seen any examples containing this phrase

Comment: Usually we say "in a while". I'll see you in a while. It's been a while since I've seen you. When will you be coming home? Not for a while. How long it is depends on the context.

Comment: So if I used this phrase, it would be a mistake, right?

Comment: I've heard this phrase plenty before, but mostly in reference to the past: *I haven't seen my cousin Larry in some time. I wonder what he's up to.* This is more emphatic than something like "a while". It's more equivalent to "quite a while" or other intensified phrase. The other comments make me wonder if this might be a regionalism.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you *can't* say "in some time", but it doesn't sound natural.

You can also say "See you sometime", and it sounds natural, but informal and a little indifferent. It (to me) implies you'll probably see them at some point, but you don't really care, or wouldn't go out of your way for it. "See you 'round" gives off a similar vibe.

For informal but not indifferent, I'd go with "See you later", "See you soon" or "See you sometime soon"

I can't think of a formal way to express that sentiment with a very vague time. If you are trying to be formal, and you want to say this, I think it'd be best to estimate a time frame (ie "I'll see you in a few weeks" for 2/3/4 weeks), although "I'll see you sometime soon" is at least a little formal.

Comment: If you say "There's no reason you can't say "in some time", you should point out an example where you would use it. Of course you can say anything you want, but that does not make the case that it is proper or even used in English.

Comment: @user3169 This phrase is certainly acceptable at least in some regions. E.g. *I've been working on this project for some time.* NB that correct usage places verbal emphasis on *some*, not *time*.

Comment: @user3169, I mean to say there is nothing inherently ungrammatical about it. I wouldn't use that construction probably, but if someone did the meaning would be clear and they didn't break any rules of grammar that I'm aware of.

Comment: Also a Google search of "in some time" will bring up a good number of results, such as ["Oddly, Mrs. Spencer hadn't brought up his name in some time"](https://books.google.com/books?id=9jIoCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=see+you+%22in+some+time%22&source=bl&ots=Z3PSiu1iFv&sig=o_-c9jON5tc7-UQdPc8c4_s00xo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidg7iV7Z3LAhUJQCYKHT6uC4QQ6AEITDAI#v=onepage&q=see%20you%20%22in%20some%20time%22&f=false)

Comment: That's just not how the idiom is used. Sure, you can say that in the sense that you won't be arrested or attacked by a crazed mob, but any listeners will be confused what you mean.

Comment: @Sarah I wasn't trying to be critical or doubting it exists, just that adding an example using it would make a more compete answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Some time" is an idiom meaning "a long time".

It is generally used either in the negative, some variation of "not for some time ...", or with a word like "since" or "until" (depending on whether it's future or past), "it's been some time since ...", "it will be some time until ..."

It is often used with the prepositions "in" and "for". "For some time" means "for a long time". "In some time" means essentially the same. In most cases they are interchangeable. "I haven't seen Bob in some time." "I haven't seen Bob for some time." Both mean, "I haven't seen Bob for a long time", or "It has been a long time since I last saw Bob." (If anyone on this board can explain when and why they're different, please help me out!)

"Tell Mr Jones that it will be some time before I am able to reschedule our appointment." It will be a long time.

"Tell Mr Jones I won't be able to see him for some time." Similar meaning.

The phrase is not used the way you use it in your example. You could say, "I won't be able to see you for some time" if you mean that it will be a long time. Or if you mean an indefinite period of time, you could say, "I'll see you in a while" or "I'll see you again sometime."

Comment: You're mixing "some time", "in some time" and "for some time" without really explaining the difference. "For some time" seems much more natural to me than "in some time".

Comment: @ColleenV Care to explain what you see as the difference? In the cases that come to my mind they'd mean essentially the same: "I haven't seen Bob in some time", "I haven't seen Bob for some time".

Comment: If "in some time" means "a long time, why wouldn't you say "It has been in some time since we had deer"? The three phrases aren't interchangeable in every context, only in some. You're giving a lot of examples of different ways to use "some time" but you haven't explained why you choose in, for, or no preposition at all. I think maybe it's a little bit of a native speaker blind-spot, because it seems obvious that the way you've phrased your examples is correct, but I can't say exactly why each is correct over a different way. I wish I had something more helpful to contribute :(

Comment: @ColleenV Ah, excellent point. I've updated my answer to perhaps be a little more clear. (And to confess where I can't give a complete answer.)